# Gutenberg getBlockIndex in save() function

Tags: javascript, block-editor

In my block's `edit()` function i'm getting the index of each inner block:

```
// a block used in innerblocks
edit( { attributes, setAttributes, clientId } ) {

    let blockIndex = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getBlockIndex( clientId );
    
    ...
```

This works fine. However i tried the same in `save()` but I get index `-1` for each block. How can I make `getBlockIndex()` work in `save()`?

I need to add index number to class names of inner blocks in HTML.

Comment: this doesn't make sense, and is an antipattern. A block should always return the same output given the same attributes, if you succeed in what you are doing you will immediately face block validation problems that stop you in your tracks. Save components should ***only*** use block attributes, they shouldn't select things, use state, have interactive components, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `wp.select` in your save component, a save component can *only* use the block attributes. If you generate markup from using data from other sources then it will fail block validation.

If you want data such as the index of the block, you need to store it in the attributes in the edit component, or render the block in PHP.

The same goes for other "effects", you should not do these things in a save component:

- use state
- make HTTP requests
- retrieve data that didn't come from block attributes
- interactive components
- query the data store
- react hooks e.g `useEffect` or `useCallback`
- prompt the user for data
- extract data from DOM nodes or global variables

The job of a save component is to take the blocks attributes and turn them into static HTML that gets saved in the database. Any interactivity or effects that do work need to go in the edit component or elsewhere, and their results stored in attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I added the blockindex to an attribute then used that in save().

Comment: But we can use [`<RichText />`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-editor/#richtext) to prompt the user for data, right?

Comment: In an edit component yes, but in a save component? Never. That doesn't make sense, save components are _never_ rendered and shown to the user, there is no way to prompt the user for data in a save component. Interactive components must go in the edit component. The only purpose of a save component is to generate HTML static strings that are going to be saved in the database

Comment: Okay, I got that. There was confusion here: https://nimb.ws/dWnq96 Since it was used in the save function. I assume the <RichText /> in save returns the value from the editor, not from the frontend. Am I right?

Comment: `<RichText.Content />` and `<RichText/>` are not the same component, you cannot use interactive components inside a save component. You can trivially test this by using the component and if it works then it works, if it does not then it will not, and it will be glaringly obvious that it's broken

Comment: This answer is given credit here: https://css-tricks.com/?p=374381&preview=1&_ppp=538d439169 Hopefully, you can have a look before I ask the editor to publish.